# Chart line does not draw

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am having a typical scenario where in a chart line does not draw for me.

When I try takng the same data and put it in jsfiddle, it seems like working.

Attachng the screen shot from my application which does not show the line but only the dots.
[image: Chart showing dots only]

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/10/) I am talking about

```
$(function () {
    $('#chartContainer').highcharts({chart: {
            renderTo: 'chartContainer',
            type: 'spline',
            marginTop:50,
            spacingBottom: 5,
            marginBottom: 100
        },
        credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
        title: {
            text: 'Product health'

        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                month: '%e %b',
                year: '%b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max:100,
            tickInterval:10,
            title: {
                text: 'Passrate'
            }
        },
        legend: {
                        title: {
                            text: '<span style="font-size: 9px; color: #666; font-weight: normal">To toggle between different branches click on the branch names in the legend</span>',
                            style: {
                                fontStyle: 'italic'
                            }
                        },
                        layout: 'horizontal'
                    },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                     return 'Branch: <b>'+ this.series.name +
                        '</b><br/>Date: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b',this.x)+
                            '</b><br/>Pass rate: '+ this.y +'%'+
                             '</b><br/>Pass count: '+  this.point.options.passCount+
                         '</b><br/>Total count: '+  this.point.options.totalCount;
            }
        },
         plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: 'True',
                    format: '{y} %'
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                crop: 'false',
                overflow: 'none'
            }
        },
        series: [{name: 'xyz', data:[{x: Date.UTC(2013,10,2),y: 100,passCount: 4,totalCount: 4},{x: Date.UTC(2013,10,6),y: 100,passCount: 3,totalCount: 3}]}]

    });
});
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue on my Chrome and Firefox, there is always a line connected two dots.

Comment: How we can reproduce this issue and which browser do you use? Because fiddle seems to working correctly.

Comment: Hi Paul and Sebastian, I am using IE 10 and 11. I have not tried the same in Chrome, but the fiddle definitely works in Chrome.

Comment: So please let us know if fiddle works properly in IE10/11 or not

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that earlier, the fiddler works fine in IE 10/11. Only the chart in the application has a problem. How would I provide you a repro?

Comment: Well, we support javascript scripts, but your application is prepared in phonegap or different environment?